# How to query WidgetKit if my widgets are being used?

Tags: ios, widgetkit

I would like to check if the user added my widgets to the Home Screen, is there an API for this? I could not find one. `WidgetCenter.getCurrentConfigurations` returns all available widgets served by the app, not the used ones.

The reasons I look for such an API are:

1. I would like to report usages of the widgets.
2. I would like to decide if I should trigger timeline reloads via `WidgetCenter` when state changes happen in the app.

Comment: were you ale to solve it? doesn't widgetCenter.getCurrentConfigurations gets the used one by the app? , this is what I'm currently seeing.

Comment: It was what I've seen when I tried but it has been a while since then. I am not sure if the behaviour of the method changed or apple suggested another way to achieve what we want. I don't know the current situation but we were not able to find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Method `WidgetCenter.shared.getCurrentConfigurations` *does* return the number of user configured widgets:

```
WidgetCenter.shared.getCurrentConfigurations { widgets 
    if let widgets = widgets, widgets.count > 0 {
        // User did configure at least one widgets
    }
}
```

This is also according the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/widgetcenter/getcurrentconfigurations(_:)):

> Retrieves information about user-configured widgets.

Comment: Thanks! This has allowed me to get rid of a complicated code that was writing a flag from a widgetkit process :).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think such an API exists (yet).

For 1. I would write something that identifies the widget in a shared user defaults container. Hooks for that would be `getSnapshot(for:,in:,completion:)` or `getTimeline(for:,in:,completion:)` with `context.isPreview == false`. Now the difficult part is that you don't get any id for the widget so you cannot distinguish two widgets with the same configuration (afaik).

For 2. I think this is (and will be) opaque, so you just tell the `WidgetCenter` to reload specific or all configurations and when no widget is currently placed on the home screen nothing happens.